# What is the relationship between the lengths of the binary and decimal representations of a number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If a is 1024 bits, then how many digits will its decimal representation have?

Comment: The 1024-bit number $\underbrace{000\ldots0}_{1024}$ has one digit.

Comment: @dfeuer That's misleading... It's like saying that the 100-digit number $\underbrace{000\ldots0}_{100}$ has one digit.

Comment: @CaseyChu, the question just isn't specific enough to give a good answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bits *are* binary numerals.  If you have an 8-bit numeral, say 10110001, that is exactly an 8-bit binary numeral.  In fact "bit" is an abbreviation of "binary digit".

When converted to decimal, an $n$-bit binary numeral will have at most $kn$ decimal digits, rounded up, where $k = \log_{10} 2 \approx 0.301$.  So an 8-bit binary numeral, say 10110001, will have around $8\cdot 0.301 = 2.408$ decimal digits—round up to 3.  In this example, $10110001_2 = 177_{10}$, and 177 has three decimal digits.

A 1024-bit binary numeral therefore has about 309 decimal digits.

Comment: thanks for reply, your answer is really helpful.

Comment: why k=log2 base 10.

Answer (score 0):

This is just plain wrong.

The number of bits base 2 in 9 is 4

The number of bits base 2 in 10 is 4

Therefore, according to the answer.. regardless of the value of k
The number of digits in both 9 and 10 will be the same...

which is just plain wrong. :)

i think the presumption of that answer is that the number of bits
in n is the same as log2(n)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually found using two Log functions. (LOG<sub>O</sub>T)*(LOG<sub>O</sub>N) where O is your original base, T is your target base, and N is the number you want to translate. This will give you the number of digits you need to represent N number of values in the other base.

This stems from the number of digits your O base is represented by in the target base, a measure that will give you the value of a multiplier which, when multiplied by the number of digits in your number from the O base, gives you the number of digits the target base requires to support the translated number.

Note, any decimal value over zero should be rounded up.

This has been useful in translating desired supported values to hexadecimal array length.